# Semantic-ui: checkbox onDisable function couldn't be called

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, semantic-ui

My code is using the semantic-ui checkbox module. I have a checkbox. I need to call a function after the state of the checkbox changed. Just like the jQuery checkbox change function. But when I use semantic-ui checkbox, I just can't call the 'onDisable' function. And I always got the state of checkbox before it changed. But I just want to get the checkbox state after it changed.

HTML code

```
<div class="ui checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="high" > <label>High</label>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
    var $checkbox = $(".ui.checkbox input");

    $checkbox.checkbox({
        onEnable: function() {
            console.log("onEnable!" + $checkbox.prop("checked"));
        },
        onDisable: function() {
            console.log("onDisable!" + $checkbox.prop("checked"));
        },
        onChange: function() {
            console.log("onChange!" + $checkbox.prop("checked"));
        }
    });
```

The usage of semantic-ui checkbox can be seen [here](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/checkbox.html#/settings).

when I click the checkbox (the checkbox state is checked), it always display

```
onChange!true
onEnable!true
```

I just want

```
onChange!false
onEnable!false
```

And when I click the checkbox (the checkbox state is unchecked), it always display

```
onChange!false
onEnable!false
```

And I just want

```
onChange!true
onEnable!true
```

Turns out that the semantic-ui checkbox callback function didn't match what I need.

My question is :

1.Why the 'onDisable' function isn't be called?

2.How can I use semantic-ui checkbox like jQuery checkbox onchange function?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with the selector.  Semantic UI's checkbox works against the containing div, not the input. The following isn't optimal, but works

```
var $cont = $(".ui.checkbox");
var $checkbox = $(".ui.checkbox input");
$cont.checkbox({
  onEnable: function() {
    console.log("onEnable!" + $checkbox.prop("checked"));
  },
  onDisable: function() {
    console.log("onDisable!" + $checkbox.prop("checked"));
  },
  onChange: function(x) {
    console.log("onChange!" + $checkbox.prop("checked"));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1/ onDisable and onEnable callbacks are for disabling/enabling the checkbox, not checking/unchecking (there are onChecked and onUnchecked callbacks for them), see the **set enabled** and **set disabled** [behaviors](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/checkbox.html#behavior), related to the input *disabled* attribute.

2/ [documentation](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/checkbox.html#/settings) says that the *context* (= this) of the callbacks is the HTML input element, then you can use it as so.

```js
$(function() {

  var $checkbox = $(".ui.checkbox");

  $checkbox.checkbox({
    onEnable: function() {
      console.log("onEnable!" + $(this).prop("checked"));
    },
    onDisable: function() {
      console.log("onDisable!" + $(this).prop("checked"));
    },
    onChange: function() {
      console.log("onChange!" + $(this).prop("checked"));
    }
  });

  $('#disable').click(function() {
    $checkbox.checkbox('set disabled');
  });

  $('#enable').click(function() {
    $checkbox.checkbox('set enabled');
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/master/dist/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/master/dist/semantic.js"></script>

<div class="ui checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="high">
  <label>High</label>
</div>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="disable">disable</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="enable">enable</a>
```

By the way, the onEnable and onDisable callbacks seems not to be fired as expected. jsfiddle version : https://jsfiddle.net/gtgco92h/